# Why wouldn't sending and receiving over the same frequencies work?

Tags: networking, dsl

DOCSIS and DSL use different frequency ranges for upstream and downstream. I thought of a way of improving efficiency, to allow using the whole frequency range for both upstream and downstream:

- Send data and receive data at the same time
- XOR the cable with what you send to find what you receive

Why would this solution be inferior to allocation different frequency ranges to upstream and downstream?

Comment: There are many variations of DSL technology; you are probably referring to ADSL.  *"XOR the cable with what you send"* -- Exclusive ORing is a logical operation.  The signals on the wire are analog (modulated with the digital information).  You cannot perform a logical operation on analog signals.  However the transmitted signal can be "subtracted" from the received signal, a process known as echo cancellation. An older xDSL tech called SHDSL used echo cancellation.  Signal levels had to be calibrated during the training phase of connection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gigabit Ethernet works similarly to what you proposed. Each of the 4 twisted pairs is simultaneously bidirectional by each transceiver subtracting its own signal from what's on the wire.

I note that your proposal only works for diplexing (full duplex, 2-way multiplexing), not n-way multiplexing where n > 2.

DOCSIS can't work that way for two reasons. First, because everyone in your neighborhood is on the same wire, so n > 2. Second, DOCSIS HFC networks were built for cable TV and have amps that only amplify frequencies below ~50-200MHz in the upstream direction, and only amplify frequencies above that "split frequency" in the downstream direction. So you'd have to do massive infrastructure upgrades to make it so all frequencies are equally amplified in both directions.

I suppose DSL could work like you propose, but I imagine there are other hassles and constraints of that unshielded, unbalanced medium that makes it better to use the frequency division multiplexing it uses today.